# Visual Studio 2010 - Packaging Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

Hy, when I'm trying to package my "Empty SharePoint Solution" in Visual Studio 2010 I'm getting this error "The Project Item "ItemName" cannot be deployed through a Feature in a Sandboxed Solution". The Solution contains a "Sequential Workflow". I have taken an "Empty SharePoint Solution" so that I could make it sandboxed.

I hope anyone is able to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens, because Sequential Workflow project is not be implemented as Sandbox Solution. Sandbox Solution has restrictions. If you want use Sequential Workflow, you should use Farm Solution. More see

[What Can Be Implemented in Sandboxed Solutions in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/gg615464.aspx)

and

[How to Create and Deploy Declarative Workflows in Sandboxed Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/gg615452.aspx)

Good luck!

Comment: It has to be a sanboxed solution. Now i will try to make it as a costume workflow action. Thank you for your help!